# Confusion over return from function

Tags: python

I am new to Python development and I have seen a code which seems to be too complicated for me. The actual code

```
def somefunction():
    return 5+3
```

When I called the function it returns me the answer as `8`...

The code method that I saw on the internet:

```
def somefunction():
    return( somefunction(5+3))
```

When I called this function it gave me an error like `TypeError: somename() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

I am a bit confused about the second method; can it be done like this? In which case we use the function in the second method...

Comment: Where did you see it?

Comment: @Christian check this link and navigate to python section ..you can seee the code ..but that code works fine..

Comment: @user3783784 which link?

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Do you want to know if functions can call themselves (yes; it's called recursion)? Do you want to know why this one doesn't work (you are trying to pass arguments when the function defines no parameters)? You should really read [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Comment: @jonrsharpe i gave parameter a and when i called the functin like somefunction(1) it throws error ..how can i call this function ??

Comment: @user3783784 why are you asking me a question about someone else's answer? You aren't even telling me what error you get. You really need to review the basics - follow the link in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 3):

The second example utilizes recursion. The problem is that in the function:

```
def somefunction():
    return somefunction(5+3)
```

we are doing `somefunction(5+3)`, which means that we expect that `somefunction` takes a parameter (by giving an argument of `5+3`), when it does not. Hence an error is given.

This can be fixed by giving a parameter definition:

```
def somefunction(a): # a is a parameter
    return somefunction(5+3)
```

Though, note that:

1. This is still not a very good function (why does it take `a` and return `5 + 3`).
2. It shows infinite recursion.

**UPDATE**

As per OPs request.

```
def add_three(number):
    return number + 3
```

Comment: ..but when i called it like somefunction(1) it throws me error

Comment: I think you need to get well with fundamentals of python programming. Better you can complete course from : http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python
it requires hardly your 1 week on the basis of 2 hr per day. Good luck.

Comment: @Gaurang ..can you tell me how to call this recrusive function ??

Comment: @user3783784 You would first need to understand what recursion exactly is. For that, please see to what `kzs` and `jonrsharpe` linked. Next, I am editing my question, with what could have been the right function.

Comment: @GaurangTandon that doesnt show nothing in recrusion ..i need to know how to call the recrusive function ..

Comment: @user3783784 why do you need or want a recursive function (or, for that matter, *any* function) to add two numbers? What's wrong with `5 + 3`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i know this can be done without recrusive but i would like to do it with recrusive ..i have done def somefunction(a): # a is a parameter
    return somefunction(5+3) ..and called function like somefunction(1) ..it shows me error ,..

Comment: @user3783784 well **of course** it does, as Gaurang tells you in the answer. Think it through, it's not difficult: `somefunction` calls `somefunction`, which calls `somefunction`, which calls... **What did you think was going to happen?!**